# Fetch repos from Github and display in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to fetch Github api but I constantly received error messages; The error messages were:

1. is not a function at repo.map
2. url was undefined.
3. res was undefined

I want to avoid using Axios as I want to get practice more using hooks.

Can anyone spot which part that I missed out?

//GithubCards.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import baseURL from "../api/GitHub";
import RepoCards from "./RepoCards";
import "./Portfolio.css";

function GithubCards(){

const [session, setSession] = useState(null);

const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

let repo = [
    baseURL(`chat-app-supabase`),
    baseURL(`3d-animation-threejs`),
    baseURL(`weather-app`),
    baseURL(`movie-api`),
    baseURL(`react-bootstrap-graphql`),
    baseURL(`react-course-meetup-app`),
];

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://github-lang-deploy.herokuapp.com/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setSession({ language: data });
        })
}, []);

repo.map(
    fetch((url) => (url, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `token ${api_key}`,
        }
    })).then((data) => {
        setSession({
            repo: [...repo, res.data],
        });
    }),
)

return(
    <div className="main-github">
        {repo.map((data, i) => (
            <RepoCard repo={data} key={i} language={language} />
        ))}
    </div>
);
}

export default GithubCards;
```

//RepoCards.js

```
import React from "react";

function RepoCard({ repo, language }) {
    return(
        <div>
            <a href={repo.html_url}>Title : {repo.name}</a>
            <p>Description : {repo.description}</p>
            <div>
                {repo.language ? (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <span>Language : {repo.language}</span>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ) : null }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RepoCard;
```